# How can i access photo privacy settings through Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I dont want to use FQL since this is taking much too much time. My app needs to get all the facebook picturs of a specific user , except private pictures.

Using graph API im first getting all pictures for a specific user, I then tried querying the privacy settings for each of these pictures using FQL but this is taking hours. The photo object doesnt have any privacy field on Graph API. D

oes anyone know a way around that without going through FQL?

Comment: Well, if the photos are not public, you'll not be able to retrieve them without having an explicit Access Token for the User...

Comment: Yes of course, this is done after the user grants access in my application. That's how I can get all the pictures. But there's no way for me to access the privacy field of a photo the graph API